# installing oracle 11g in ubuntu 10.10

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle-11g, ubuntu-10.04, installation

i'm trying to install oracle 11g database in my ubuntu 10.10, following this tutorial http://oracleabc.com/b/archives/167 but, at the step 11, the system asks for oracle password!

which password is it? i did not set anything yet! i've tried 'oracle', 'password', , (my system's) root password, but doesn't work! are there some 'default password'? how can i go ahead and finish my installation?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

It's the os user `oracle`, which you should have created in step 4:

```
# useradd -g oinstall -G dba -p password -d /home/oracle -s /bin/bash oracle
```